# Angular 10 formcontrol issue

Tags: angular

I have created an application with angular 10. Modules are loaded with loadchildren() in app.modules.ts like,

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: () => import('./views/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
}
```

In my admin.module I have imported

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

But could not possible to use formcontrol. It showing error like ,

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

this is my admin.component.ts-

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  createForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      name: ['', Validators.required],

    });
  }

}
```

this is admin.component.html-

```
<form [formGroup]="createForm">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Department Name" formControlName="name" >
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please share your routing module?

Comment: this is admin routing
-------------------------------

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }

Comment: Check this it is working. https://codesandbox.io/s/lazy-loaded-module-nlvy5?file=/src/app/orders/order-list.component.html

Comment: You state that you have imported the ReactiveFormsModule in your admin module, but have you added it to your imports array inside the admin module?

Comment: Thnx Vimal Patel :) its working fine..